# TYPO3 Powermail Sending Mail from punycode Domain

Tags: sendmail, typo3

I have a multiple Domain TYPO3 8.7. The powermail form works fine. Except when I use it in the section with the punycode domain (there is an ä in it). TYPO3 automatically creates the punycode in the backend. But the logs from mail sending contains the following:

```
Mon, 02 Jul 2018 16:09:27 +0200 [CRITICAL] request="48c027e568ecd" component="In2code.Powermail.Controller.FormController": Mail could not be sent - ["This is already a Punycode string"]
```

So powermail say "it is a punycode, i cannot transform it" but TYPO3 is transforming it automatically ... or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Quickfix: **`vendor/typo3/cms/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php`**

```
/**
 * Returns an ASCII string (punicode) representation of $value
 *
 * @param string $value
 * @return string An ASCII encoded (punicode) string
 */
public static function idnaEncode($value)
{
    if(strpos($value, 'xn--') !== false){
        return $value;
    }
    [...]
```

May you create a issue on: https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/issues